# opening a WPF application from winforms app

Tags: wpf, winforms, process

is there any way for me to open an WPF application from a WinForms app ?

I've been trying this

```
   ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"path-to-app-exe");
```

But no luck, 
hope someone can give me some pointers.

Thanks
/sushiBite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not need any advanced settings for startinfo use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) method like this:

`Process.Start(@"path-to-app-exe");`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [`Process.Start(procInfo);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the start method on a process object:

```
Process it = new Process();
        it.StartInfo = procInfo;
        it.Start();
```